# Input variable into Java Script

Tags: javascript, variables, safari

I am attempting to take a list of variables that I have generated using apple automator and input those variables into my Javascript, but I haven't been having much luck.  My current code looks like this:

```
function run(input, parameters) {
    var safari = Application("Safari");
    safari.includeStandardAdditions = true;
    
    var jsScript ="jsScript += document.getElementById('search-name').value = '"
    + input[0] + input[1]
    + "';";
    "jsScript += document.getElementById('search-location').value = '"
    + input[2] + input[4]
    + "';";
    jsScript += "document.getElementById('wp-search').click();";
    
    safari.doJavaScript(jsScript, { in:safari.windows[0].currentTab});

    return jsScript;
}
```

I am getting the error can't find variable: jsScript.  Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am using apple automator so I don't really know how I can provide more of the code.  I am attempting to fill in a web form, but my inputs will change frequently.  I am already able to get a text box pop-up that takes an input and saves the variable, but I am having trouble getting the jsScript to recognize the variables that I input.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase there are others out there that were trying to do the same thing.  I figured out the answer to my question with a little help from a co worker.  The following script will take a variable and input it into a string for a webform search:

function run(input, parameters) {

```
var safari = Application("Safari");
safari.includeStandardAdditions = true;

var jsScript = "";
    jsScript += "document.getElementById('search-name').value = '" 
        + input[0] + " " + input[2] + "';";
    jsScript += "document.getElementById('search-location').value = '"
        + input[5] + " " + input[6] + "';";
    jsScript += "document.getElementById('wp-search').click();";

safari.doJavaScript(jsScript, { in:safari.windows[0].currentTab});

return input;
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).